# SQL Server Agent Jobs not showing in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, jobs, agent

In SSMS not showing jobs under the Sql Server agent jobs folder, however I can query the jobs in MSDB. How do i fix this issue? Thanks When I try to open the jobs folder below is the error message.

[image]

Comment: check if SQL Server Agent is started or not.

Comment: The SQL Server agent is running, I just checked the sql server configuration tool

Comment: Which version of SQL Server and SSMS are you running?  I've had a few troubles accessing SQL Server 2008 r2 from SSMS 2016.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014 SSMS however my server is SQL Server 2008

Comment: Server Name: aapdbtest
Error Number: 529
Severity: 16
State: 2
Procedure: sp_get_composite_job_info
Line Number: 192

Answer (score 0):

Use SSMS 2008.  The way jobs are handled has changed over different versions of SQL Server, and the SSMS tools are written for that specific version without backward compatibility.

Comment: Do you have some documentation to confirm this? I've been using SSMS 2016 CTPs to interact with Agent jobs on 2008R2 for about 6 months (and SSMS 2012 before that), and not had any trouble.

Comment: No, I speak only from personal experience.  I have used SSMS 2012 to create a job on a 2008 server, and it resulted in errors.  But creating the job the same way in SSMS 2008 worked fine.  It only makes sense that when a SSMS tool writes code for you, it is going to write code that will work in the version of SQL server that it was designed for, and may use features that did not exist in older versions.   It won't necessarily happen every time, obviously, but it *can* happen any time.